# #include .cpp in .h file before the end of include guard

Tags: c++, header-files

I have recently received an assignment which defines a .h file. In this .h file at the bottom it #includes the .cpp file. For example

```
#ifndef CLASS_H
#define CLASS_H

class MyClass
{
  //variablles and methods
};

#include MyClass.cpp

#endif
```

Now the problem comes in when I try to write the definitions for the .cpp file. For example when I try to define the constructor is will give me an error along the lines of

```
 error: ‘MyClass’ does not name a type
```

I also incur errors when I try to define operator overloading functions

I know these errors are only applicable to the above mentioned case because when i #include my .h file in my .cpp file, it compiles perfectly

I am not allowed to change any of my .h files in this assignment

Comment: Why would you want to do that?

Comment: If you're going to include the `.cpp` file in the `.h` file, then don't try to compile the `.cpp` file.

Comment: Putting `MyClass.cpp` in the header makes no sense. Take it out. And remember to include the header in the cpp file.

Comment: I'm not sure behind the reasoning of their methods. But is their anything I could do to get it to compile correctly ?

Comment: @KeatonPennells To get what to compile correctly? If you're including the `.cpp` file in some other file, you shouldn't be trying to compile the `.cpp` file, just like you normally include `.h` files from other files, so you don't try to compile them.

Comment: I am trying to get my .cpp file to compile correctly. If i include the '.h' file in my '.cpp

Comment: ... as usual, it compiles without any errors. But when my .cpp file is included in my .h files I get a myriad of different errors

Comment: Do you forget quotes? It should be `#include "MyClass.cpp"`

Comment: @KeatonPennells Why is that surprising to you? When we construct `.h` files such that they can be included in other files, we *don't* try to compile them, right? It's not the extension that matters, it's the logic. Your `.cpp` file is constructed like everyone else constructs `.h` files, and it won't compile for the same reason `.h` files aren't directly compiled.

Comment: Your prof/TA/whatever is not doing the best possible job. Including .cpp files is bad on too many levels to be enumerated here. You will do wise if you take what they tell you with a big heap of salt.

Answer (score 1):

Don't do this in a header file:
    #include MyClass.cpp
Compile MyClass.cpp separately and within Myclass.cpp, have:

```
#include MyClass.hpp
```

or

```
#include MyClass.h
```

Whatever you have.